# cannot upload workflow wsp file to sharepoint solution gallery

Tags: workflow, error

Today when I try to upload a workflow `wsp` solution to SharePoint solution gallery, I got this error message. Any idea what's going wrong?

[image]

Comment: First check your logs with correlation ID.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation ID is a very traditional way of SharePoint to show errors. Which may not be very helpful for a user to identify the reason behind the error.

To get all the details regarding the error, you need to open to log files and see for the generated `Correlation ID`.

1. Goto machine where `SharePoint` is installed.
2. Open the location `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS`
3. Here the log files will be listed and you need to open the latest one in notepad.
4. Search for the `Correlation Id` which you have received.

Once you get to know the exact error details, you will know what is going wrong.

Comment: It turns out only me as the designer can upload this solution, anyone else will receive this error message, is it because there is a digital signature or some knid of a restriction within SharePoint Designer?

Comment: @Celia : You mean to say that you can upload this `wsp` through SharePoint Designer, otherwise no?